# Partial View with ng-route vs ng-show/ng-hide which one should I use?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have four to five tab views in my app. So clicking on each tab I'll show content based on the tab selection.

I tried two approach one is `ng-route` and another one is `ng-show/ng-hide`. I feel `ng-show/ng-hide` is good at **performance level** and I think I should follow the same. Here is what I tried

First Approach **ng-route**

*main.php*

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", ["ngRoute"]);
testApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/tab1", {
templateUrl: "tab1.php"
});
$routeProvider.when("/tab2", {
templateUrl: "tab2.php"
});
$routeProvider.when("/tab3", {
templateUrl: "tab3.php"
});
$routeProvider.when("/tab4", {
templateUrl: "tab4.php"
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({
templateUrl: "tab1.php"
});
});

testApp.controller('testContr',function($scope){
//controller statements goes here
});


<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#/tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#/tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#/tab3">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#/tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

tab1.php

```
 <div>
        tab1 content goes here
    </div>
```

*tab2.php*

```
<div>
    tab2 content goes here
</div>
```

*tab3.php*

```
<div>
    tab3 content goes here
</div>
```

*tab4.php*

```
<div>
    tab4 content goes here
</div>
```

Second approach **ng-show/ng-hide**

*main.php*

```
            var testApp = angular.module("testApp", []);

        testApp.controller('testContr',function($scope){
            $scope.view = 'tab1'// tab1 by default
            $scope.setView = function($newView){
                $scope.view = $newView;
            }
            //controller statements goes here

        });


 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active" role="presentation" ng-click="setView('tab1')"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-click="setView('tab2')"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-click="setView('tab3')"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-click="setView('tab4')"><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php require_once 'tab1.php';
    require_once 'tab2.php';
    require_once 'tab3.php';
    require_once 'tab4.php'; ?>
```

Content in those are listed in the main.php but on condition with ng-show

tab1.php

```
<div ng-show="view == 'tab1'">
        tab1 content goes here
        </div>
```

tab2.php

```
<div ng-show="view == 'tab2'">
tab2 content goes here
</div>
```

tab3.php

```
<div ng-show="view == 'tab3'">
tab3 content goes here
</div>
```

tab4.php

```
<div ng-show="view == 'tab4'">
tab4 content goes here
</div>
```

I see the benefits of partial view with `ng-route`, which is manageable chunk of code. Which I can achieve php include file(each file with separate view and include them all in main file) and `ng-show`.
My app doesn't need to care about **URL Navigation** as of now.
When I try the above two approach I see `ng-show` is faster and I can avoid `ng-route.js` file as well(reduces file load time).

Is there anything am I thinking wrong. Any suggestion on which to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In addition to what @DilumN has said, using `ng-route` also allows you to do deep linking (of sorts) into your tabs i.e. you can provide a URL to someone and that would open into the exact tab you want to point at.
- Also, `ng-route` is *meant* for this task, as opposed to `ng-hide/show` which is meant to `display: none` content.
- Last but not least, `ng-route` allows for easier tests (you're writing tests right? wink).
- You can also separate out concerns using ngRoute, and in the end, this will prevent spaghetti code. If you come from a jQuery background, the `ng-show` method might look more intuitive, but the `ng-route` method ironically, is the *more* Angular way of doing this.

Comment: I forgot tests :) . It's one another consideration & developers who are going to maintain your code in future will not blame you as well. :)

Comment: Hi @nikjohn Yes I was from jquery background. That's why I am just thinking to show/hide content as we did earlier with jquery :) Thanks for test suggestion I didn't went till angularjs test. As I said in the question as of now URL Navigation is not needed. +1 I'll follow the anuglar way of doing. I'll use ng-route as you said.

Answer (score 1):

For this approach `ng-show` have some disadvantages as well. Because you are using `ng-show` to show hide tabs, when you load the page initially all those views will be loaded into your DOM & `ng-show` uses css show/hide to show content accordingly. If your content get bigger & bigger the HTML will also grow bigger.

And also if you want to handle separate `controllers` for each tabs one day, the better way is using separate `ui-views` for each tab.

For a simple `static` tab content `ng-show` is fine, but if you have a feeling that it will be more complex in future, my suggestion is to go for separate `routes` & `controllers`.

So at the end of the day decision is yours by thinking about the future growth of the project.

Comment: Hi thanks +1 for your help. What do you mean by separate `routes`? Can I use routes separately ? I mean multiple navigation?

Comment: I mean, use separate ng-routes with separate controllers for each tab. Then it will be easy for you to manage the code

Comment: Thank you @DilumN your answer helped me a lot.